# An array of conditions for phpactiverecord

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I have so many combinations of conditions that could possibly go into a db call that I can't possibly make a separate call for each one. I'd have way too many if/else statements.

So I wanted to instead push conditions into an array to dynamically build both conditional statement and values being passed in. 
So:

```
    $cond_values = array();
    $cond_values[] = $lender->id;
    $cond_string = "lender_id = ?";

    if (something) {
      $cond_string .= " AND search_id =?";
      $cond_values[] = $search_id; 
    }
    if (something_else) {
      $cond_string .= " AND cust_id =?";
      $cond_values[] = $cust_id; 
    }

    $matches = Match::all(array(
      "select" => $select,
      "conditions" => array($cond_string, $cond_values),
      "order" => $order,
      "joins" => $joins
    ));
```

But this only works if $cond_values has 0 or 1 elements in it. More than one value and I get a "No bound parameter for index 1" error. It seems that it would only work if I did:

```
    $matches = Match::all(array(
      "select" => $select,
      "conditions" => array($cond_string, $cond_values[0],$cond_values[1] ),
      "order" => $order,
      "joins" => $joins
    ));
```

But the amount of values would vary so I couldn't do that. I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: use `array_unshift()` to push your `$cond_string` onto the beginning of your `$cond_values` array and then pass that array to `Match::all()`:

```
$cond_values = array();
$cond_values[] = $lender->id;
$cond_string = "lender_id = ?";

if (something) {
  $cond_string .= " AND search_id =?";
  $cond_values[] = $search_id; 
}
if (something_else) {
  $cond_string .= " AND cust_id =?";
  $cond_values[] = $cust_id; 
}

array_unshift($cond_values, $cond_string);

$matches = Match::all(array(
  "select" => $select,
  "conditions" => $cond_values,
  "order" => $order,
  "joins" => $joins
));
```

Comment: perfect! you're a lifesaver!